# How to Setup Identity in Database for NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

We are using NHibernate 2.

I've got a new table I created that looks like this:

```
Table: CategoryDependency
CategoryDependencyId    CategoryId    ParentCategoryId
--------------------    ----------    ----------------
      0                 0                NULL - root
      0                 1                0
      0                 44               1
```

... and so on

Notice the zeros for CategoryDependencyId.  I'm new to NH and so I set this as a PK not null in the SQL Server 2008 table definition with a default value of 0 or else I wouldn't be able to insert data into this table if I don't default it to something because it'll complain that you can't insert null for CategoryDependencyId, obviously.

So is this right?  Then will NHibernate still overwrite the CategoryDependencyId and increment it for you:

I assume you'd use this to set it up to increment:

When I run my code I get no records back:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace=".....our namespace is here" assembly="OurAssemblyNameIsHere">


    <class name="CategoryDependency" table="CategoryDependency">


          <id name="ID" type="int">
              <column name="CategoryDependencyId" />
              <generator class="increment" />

          </id>

        <property name="CategoryDependencyId" />
        <property name="CategoryId" />
        <property name="ParentCategoryId" />

    </class>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want identity generation, use `identity`.

`increment` means something different, and it shouldn't be used.

In any case, `identity` is not a good generation strategy either. If you can, go for `guid.comb` or `hilo`.